# What can cause a network connection to "flap"?

Tags: networking

There is a Linux box.

There is a bad Netapp device that serves storage.

They are in the same subnet, so theoretically, no routing needed.

**The problem:** Sometimes we can reach the LIF of the netapp, from the Linux box, sometimes we cannot (according to tcpdump it just doesn't responds).

**The Question:** what could cause such an issue?

**UPDATE#1**: created stats about when it is good, bad, with:

```
while true; do (nc -w 1 -z IPADDRESSHERE 22 && printf "good\t") || printf "bad\t"; date; sleep 1; done > testing.txt
```

So in every second, netcat tries to connect from the Linux box -> to the Netapp.

```
# grep -w bad testing.txt | wc -l; grep -w good testing.txt | wc -l
520
480
#
```

When trying 1000 times, we got an SSH 520 times, and 480 times it just timed out, so about ~52% good, ~48% bad. Maybe 50-50%? Could be some failover-like problem?

**UPDATE#2**: other interesting thing is that the bad Netapp cannot be pinged, while all the other Netapp is pingable.

Comment: Is there bond/team in place? If yes, make sure it's properly setup so you don't end up with situation like bond on switch side is set to active-backup, however on the Linux box (or Netapp) to some balanced mode (increasing total bandwith). Then you can end up with half packets lost...

Comment: Could be a loose termination in a cable, could be a device with a duplicate IP address temporarily connecting, or a hundred other things. As usual in these circumstances, wireshark or tcpdump are your friend in initial diagnoses.

Comment: switched to different port for the LIF and now it works! :) but still have to find out what is wrong with the bad port.